# Autopopulate values in LOV

Tags: java, oracle, lov, oaf

We have list of LOV on OAF page as show below. That list does increases or decrease according to search by user.

If I put or enter new manager name on 1st LOV then the values is autopopulate in 2nd LOV?

LOV list could be one two three and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

completed using for loop under lovEvent we can iterate the same values multiple times.